# django-tenant-schemas 1.10.0: TypeError: TenantTutorialMiddleware() takes no arguments

Tags: django, multi-tenant, saas

I am trying to use django-tenant-schemas 1.10.0. I have installed it and made migrations successfully. But the command "python manage.py runserver" produces the error:

> Exception ignored in thread started by: .wrapper at 0x000002282DBC2790>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\projects\django-tenant-schemas-master\django-tenant-schemas-master\examples\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "D:\projects\django-tenant-schemas-master\django-tenant-schemas-master\examples\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 147, in inner_run
>       handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
>
> File "D:\projects\django-tenant-schemas-master\django-tenant-schemas-master\examples\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
>       handler = super(Command, self).get_handler(*args, **options)
>
> File "D:\projects\django-tenant-schemas-master\django-tenant-schemas-master\examples\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 68, in get_handler
>       return get_internal_wsgi_application()
>
> File "D:\projects\django-tenant-schemas-master\django-tenant-schemas-master\examples\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 47, in get_internal_wsgi_application
>       return import_string(app_path)
>
> File "D:\projects\django-tenant-schemas-master\django-tenant-schemas-master\examples\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
>       module = import_module(module_path)
>
> File "c:\program files\python38\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>
> File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import
>
> File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
>
> File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 671, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 783, in exec_module
>
> File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>
> File "D:\projects\django-tenant-schemas-master\django-tenant-schemas-master\examples\tenant_tutorial\tenant_tutorial\wsgi.py", line 28, in 
>       application = get_wsgi_application()
>
> File "D:\projects\django-tenant-schemas-master\django-tenant-schemas-master\examples\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
>       return WSGIHandler()
>
> File "D:\projects\django-tenant-schemas-master\django-tenant-schemas-master\examples\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 151, in **init**
>       self.load_middleware()
>
> File "D:\projects\django-tenant-schemas-master\django-tenant-schemas-master\examples\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 82, in load_middleware
>       mw_instance = middleware(handler)
>
> TypeError: TenantTutorialMiddleware() takes no arguments

I'm using Postgres database. The error was the same when I tried with Django 1.11, 2.2, and 3.0.

Please someone help me!

Comment: It looks like the example in that repository isn't actually compatible with Django 1.11 and later - it's using the old style middleware. Might be worth reporting this as an issue on the project.

Comment: Thanks, solarissmoke. It is actually the maintenance problem of django-tenant-schemas. I am now using django-tenants, instead, and it is up and running well, aiding significantly in reducing development time.